# There are a small list of commands and I cant write the code (Android Studio)

Tags: android

I have some problem during my use Android Studio, if I create new project then come like a small list of command and I can’t write the code!
These pictures are description my steps if there some mistakes or not:

[image]

[image]

Here I select no theme:

[image: here i select no theme]

This list is problem:

[image: this list is problem]

Comment: You will not be able to write a code unless you create a (.java or other) file.

Comment: You can stary learning Android Application Development from here
https://in.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837

Comment: find a tutorial on youtube to start getting into development you'll find it hard if you try doing it the way you're doing and for such situations the stackoverflow community won't be much help because we don't teach we help and solve.

Answer (score 0):

You must click to add a new file, hence the list suggestions! Try clicking "Project" at the top left and you will see the folder structure (which should be empty at the moment).